# How to extract info from nested external idp access token in a custom policy?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework

I have a custom policy which produce b2c token with nested `idp_access_token`. I want my b2c token to include `email` claim. I have email (`unique_name/sub claims`) in nested `idp_access_token`. So, is it possible to have some kind of ClaimTransformation, to extract necessary data from claim `idp_access_token`?

[image]

**Update**: Inside external token I have claim `"unique_name"`. I have next claims configuration:

For Technical Profile which describes oauth interraction

```
 <Protocol Name="OAuth2"/>
 <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
 <Metadata> ..............</Metadata>
 <CryptographicKeys>...</CryptographicKeys>
 <InputClaims>...</InputClaims>
 <OutputClaims>    
     .........               
     <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="unique_name"/>                         
     <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderAccessToken" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}"/>
     </OutputClaims>
```

For RelyingParty:

```
 <RelyingParty>
        <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignIn" />
        <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
            <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
            <OutputClaims>
             ....
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderAccessToken" PartnerClaimType="idp_access_token"/>
            </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

I see that claims settings works for idp_access_token, but not for email.

External IDP token `idp_access_token`

[image: External IDP token]

**Update**

If I add default value, then in response I see it in b2c token

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="unique_name" DefaultValue="test@email.com" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a call to claims endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` and notice that email claim available as `mail`.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "....",
    "givenName": "...",
    "jobTitle": "..",
    "mail": "..",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": "..",
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": "..",
    "userPrincipalName": "..",
    "id": "...."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are logging into an eternal IDP?

In which case, you could get the email attribute via the [IDP mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-azure-ad-as-an-identity-provider-1) in the IDP ClaimsProviders element.

Comment: Yes, to external IDP. Have updated question to show that IDP mapping setup not works

Comment: Use App Insights, look at the JWT returned by the IDP and check that it contains that claim. Note: this JWT is not the access token but rather the IDP ID Token.